# Chrome and Firefox throws errors, IE does not - Ghost blog

Tags: node.js, nginx, ghost-blog

So, I have a selfhosted Ghost blog and there are a couple of odd behaviors

URL: https : //prusik.io/jubbaonjeans/

The cover image loads just fine in IE, but refuses to load in Chrome (for Windows and Android) or Firefox. Here's the code from the source:

```
<header class="main-header " style="background-image: url(/jubbaonjeans/content/images/2015/01/CoverForBlog-7.jpg)">
```

In addition, I have a script for Disqus comments. Similar behavior where it works in IE, but not Chrome or Firefox

URL: https://prusik.io/jubbaonjeans/mnrega-and-welfare/

I am using the instructions here (https :// help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1454924-ghost-installation-instructions) to enable Disqus on my blog. (odd URL as I am only allowed 2 links in this post)

Finally, the Ghost image uploader (For  cover image and post images) throws a weird error. I am still able to upload images, but the error remains. Again, works just fine in IE

Error: [https://prusik.io/jubbaonjeans/content/images/2015/01/UploaderIssue.JPG](http://Error)

Also, I *was* a programmer at one point and now into InfoSec. My knowledge of CSS and `HTML5` programming is basic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read this: http://lollyrock.com/articles/content-security-policy/. Should help.

Comment: @Rafik Thanks a ton! 
Turns out CSP headers are quite crazy! 
I disable the CSP Header and Disqus loaded just fine. So, we now know where the problem lies. 
Now working on finding the right configuration for the Nginx config file. Hopefully, I will be able to get this done soon enough.
I still do not have an answer for why the cover image does not load. One at a time I guess :)

Comment: So, turns out it was all in the CSP header. Starting with a blank config and adding a whitelist of whatever was needed did the trick! Thanks Eraden!